# Comparing Dictionaries using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I need to compare two dictionaries and to update another dictionary with unmatched items

The two dictionaries are like

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> DICTONE = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();
Dictionary<string, List<String>> DICTTWO = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();
```

And the contents

```
DICTONE["KEY1"]="A"
                "B"
                "C"

DICTONE["KEY2"]="D"
                "E"
                "F"

DICTTWO["KEY1"]="A"
                "B"
                "Z"

DICTTWO["KEY3"]="W"
                "X"
                "Y"
```

The third dictionary has a class instance as value

```
Dictionary<String, MyClass> DICTRESULT = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
```

and the class is like

```
class MyClass
{
    public List<string> Additional = null;
        public List<string> Missing = null; 

    public MyClass()
        {
            Additional = new List<string>();
            Missing = new List<string>();
        }
        public MyClass(List<string> p_Additional, List<string> p_Missing)
        {
            Additional = p_Additional;
            Missing = p_Missing;
        }
}
```

The scenerio is

1. If an item in in DICTONE and NOT in DICTTWO  the add the item to MISSING list in the RESULTDICT
2. If an item in in DICTTWO and NOT in DICTTONE  the add the item to ADDITIONAL list in the RESULTDICT

the expected answer is

```
DICTRESULT["KEY1"]=ADDITIONAL LIST ---> "Z"
                   MISSING LIST    ---> "C"

DICTRESULT["KEY2"]=ADDITIONAL LIST ---> ""
                   MISSING LIST    ---> "D"
                                        "E"
                                        "F"
DICTRESULT["KEY3"]=ADDITIONAL LIST ---> ""
                   MISSING LIST    ---> "W"
                                        "X"
                                        "Y"
```

is there any way to do this using LINQ

Comment: Looks like homework, could you show what you've already done?

Comment: Not much, he already asked a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226123/how-to-compare-two-xml-files-in-c-using-xml-to-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's an attempt, assuming `first` and `second` are the dictionaries in question.

```
var items = from key in first.Keys.Concat(second.Keys).Distinct()
            let firstList = first.GetValueOrDefault(key) ?? new List<string>()
            let secondList = second.GetValueOrDefault(key) ?? new List<string>()
            select new { Key = key,
                         Additional = secondList.Except(firstList),
                         Missing = firstList.Except(secondList) };
var result = items.ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                                x => new MyClass(x.Additional, x.Missing));
```

This is completely untested, mind you. I haven't even tried to compile it. It also requires an extra extension method:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>
    (this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
     TKey key)
{
    TValue value;
    dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)
    return value;
}
```